# Ubuntu 20.04 and "Dummy output"

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

After some manipulation something happen with my sound in pulseaudio.
In settings I see only "Dummy output" and no sound.

When I run command `pactl load-module module-detect` the laptop speaker starts to work but it stops working after I reboot.

How to fix this and revert to how this was working before. Reinstalling (with purge) alsa and pulse audio does not work for me. it was working fine before. Also I run live ubuntu from flash on the same laptop and it works fine as well.

Also when I try to use headset it also behave buggy.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
07:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1637]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5081]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
07:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [17aa:5081]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
07:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [17aa:5081]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: We don't know what is "some manipulation" you did.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can cause this. If you usually have an HDMI device attached, such as a monitor, and now it’s not attached, you will need to plug the monitor in again, go into your audio settings, then choose your notebook as the output. From there you can disconnect the HDMI device again.

Otherwise, you may need to apply some changes to the PulseAudio settings. What do you see when you type `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` into the terminal?

Comment: Added command output to the original question